# Why can't this program output the right exception?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

The program below outputs only:

```
0In finally
```

And not the output:

```
0 In trans_func Caught a __try exception with SE_Exception In finally
```

As I expected.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// crt_settrans.cpp
// compile with: /EHa
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <eh.h>

void SEFunc();
void trans_func( unsigned int, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* );

class SE_Exception
{
  private:
    unsigned int nSE;
  public:
    SE_Exception() {}
    SE_Exception( unsigned int n ) : nSE( n ) {}
    ~SE_Exception() {}
    unsigned int getSeNumber() { return nSE; }
};

int main( void )
{
    try
    {
        _set_se_translator( trans_func );
        SEFunc();
    }
    catch( SE_Exception e )
    {
        printf( "Caught a __try exception with SE_Exception.\n" );
    }

    system("pause");
}

void SEFunc()
{
    __try
    {
        int* buffer= new int[19];
        buffer[19]=0;
        printf("%d",buffer[19]);
        delete buffer;
    }
    __finally
    {
        printf( "In finally\n" );
    }
}

void trans_func( unsigned int u, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExp )
{
    printf( "In trans_func.\n" );
    throw SE_Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trans_func` will only be called in order to handle a structured exception.

But your code doesn't seem to trigger an SEH exception :

```
int* buffer= new int[19];
buffer[19]=0;
printf("%d",buffer[19]);
delete buffer;
```

Maybe you should try something a bit more brutal :

```
volatile int *pInt = 0x00000000;
*pInt = 20;
```

That example is directly taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/swezty51.aspx).

Comment: Well. Technically `buffer[19]=0` does invoke UB, because it writes past the buffer. This certainly won't be caught in a MSVC release build though.